# difference between 'a' and 'instanceOf'

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, bdd, chai

I'm studying the Chai BDD [API reference](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/) and I can't understand the difference between `a` and `instanceOf`.

Especially when I saw this example using `a`:

`expect([1, 2, 3]).to.be.an('array')`

And this one using `instanceOf` instead:

`expect([1, 2]).to.be.an.instanceof(Array);`

The documentation usually says something about Recommended or Not Recommended, but in this case I couldn't find anything. What I understood from the reference is that `instanceOf` can be used in case you have to check for an object constructor, whereas `a` is mainly used to checking types (is this right?). So, which is the most suitable with `array`?

Comment: I don't know Chai, but the syntax looks similar to Ruby. In Ruby, the difference is that an `Array` instance is an `Array`, an `Enumerable` and an `Object`. It is only an instance of an `Array`, so `[1,2,3].is_a?(Object)` is `true`, `[1,2,3].is_a?(Array)` is `true`, `[1,2,3].instance_of?(Array)` is `true` but `[1,2,3].instance_of?(Object)` is `false`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Well, now that you make me notice, this problem could be extended to objects too, since an object can be tested with both `a` and `instanceOf`. However I wouldn't know if it's the same as Ruby. I'll try as soon as possible.